# React to window close in clj-webdriver

Tags: clojure

I am currently using the [clj-webdriver](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver) to create several selenium test cases through the Firefox driver.

I want to react to the Firefox window being closed by the user, to ensure I cleanup the relevant atoms, but I can't seem to find any handler for this.

Does somebody have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Taxi API function called [close](https://github.com/semperos/clj-webdriver/wiki/Taxi-API-Documentation#close), which closes the browser that you can use to simulate the user closing the browser.